# How to search a value in an array inside another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a problem of find a value in an array inside another array, and use the result to `setState()`

This is the initialState:

```
this.state = 
{
    initialStudents:[
        {name:"str1",tags;["str","str",...],...},
        {name:"str2",tags;["str","str",...],...},
        ...  
       ],
   students: [
        {name:"str1",tags;["str","str",...],...},
        {name:"str2",tags;["str","str",...],...},
        ...
      ]
}
```

The code i use to find the tags:

```
findTag = (tags, target) => {
    tags.filter(tag => {
        return tag.toLowerCase().search(target.toLowerCase()) !== >-1;
    });
};

filterTag = e => {
    let updatedList = this.state.initialStudents;
        updatedList = updatedList.filter(student => {
            return this.findTag(student.tags, e.target.value);
        });
    this.setState({ students: updatedList });
};
```

The filterTag does not update the students state

Comment: where is `search` from? what is `!== >-1` doing?

Comment: I think those were just some type of pseudo-code guesses as he tried to implement the `findTag` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem, I made a few edits and put them all in this working [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/student-update-filter-zlymg).

First, I changed your `findTag` function to something like this:

```
// pass in the tags from the student, and the target tag you're searching for.
// -> return true if 1 or more matching tag, false otherwise
findTag = (tags, targetTag) => {
  // make sure you return something!
  return tags.filter(tag => {
    // check if current tag in arr matches target tag (case insensitive)
    return tag.toLowerCase() === targetTag.toLowerCase();
  }).length > 0; // check if there's 1 or more matching tag
};
```

Next, I updated the `filterTag` function in a few ways:

1. Immutably copy `this.state.initialStudents` into the local `updatedList` array. **This is necessary** so you don't mess up the current state before running `this.setState`!
2. Pass the value of the input via `this.state.filterTag` instead of `e.target.value`. This way, you'd update the filter when you click the button instead of on every time you press a key.

Here's how these changes look:

```
filterTag = e => {
  // immutably copy initial student data
  let updatedList = this.state.initialStudents
    .map(student => ({
      name: student.name,
      tags: [...student.tags]
    }))
    // remove students w/out filter tag
    .filter(student => {
      return this.findTag(student.tags, this.state.filterTag);
    });

  // update state with new student list
  this.setState({ students: updatedList });
};
```

A few other improvements I made:

1. Instead of manually setting data in `initialStudents` and `students`, I made them immutably copy the same data set from the `const initialStudents` data set. This could be done in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method if you're fetching students from a database.
2. I fixed your student object declarations - you put `tags;["str"...]` which is invalid - the semicolon `;` should be a normal colon `:`
3. I changed some `"str"` values to `"str2"` to make them unique between students

Let me know if you have questions about the codesandbox or anything else :D Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! I find I made a mistake on the return to the right value: